# How to handle screen orientation in Canvas of Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, canvas, android-canvas, screen-orientation

I am working with Canvas in Android and the issue I am facing is during the screen rotation. Let's say I start the app in portrait mode and draw something on the canvas, then on rotation some part of the canvas moves out of the screen. See the screenshots attached.

[image: Image in Portrait Mode]
[image: Image in Landscape Mode]

Code snippets from my file where Canvas is implemented (I will provide other parts if they are required just let me know through comment) :

```
    private lateinit var mBitmap: Bitmap
    private lateinit var mCanvas: Canvas
```

```
override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas)
        canvas.apply {
            drawColor(0)
            drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0f, 0f, mBitmapPaint)
            drawPath(mPath, mPaint)
        }
    }
```

```
    private fun createBitmap(w: Int, h: Int) {
        val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
        mBitmap = bitmap
        mCanvas = Canvas(bitmap)
        clear()
    }
```

```
 private fun createBitmap() {
        val p = displayDimensions
        val bitmapSize = max(p.x,p.y)
        createBitmap(bitmapSize, bitmapSize)
    }
```

```
init {
        mPaint = Paint()
        mPaint.isAntiAlias = true
        mPaint.isDither = true
        mPaint.color = foregroundColor
        mPaint.style = Paint.Style.STROKE
        mPaint.strokeJoin = Paint.Join.ROUND
        mPaint.strokeCap = Paint.Cap.ROUND
        mPaint.strokeWidth = currentStrokeWidth.toFloat()
        createBitmap()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going through a couple of blogs and SO answers I finally found the answer on Android developers documentation - [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap#createScaledBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20boolean))

My code snippet looks like :

```
override fun onSizeChanged(w: Int, h: Int, oldw: Int, oldh: Int) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh)
        val scaledBitmap: Bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mBitmap, w, h, true)
        }
        mCanvas = Canvas(scaledBitmap)
    }
```

This way you can handle the screen orientation when the device rotates. The `createScaledBitmap()` function takes care of taking the previous drawn Bitmap and scaling it according to new width and height.